# Where does GoogleAppEngineLauncher keep the local log files?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, python-logging

GoogleAppEngineLauncher can display the local log file of my app while it is running on my Mac during development. However, I can't change the font size there so I would like to use the `tail` command to watch the log file myself.

It's a shame but I can't find the log files. They are not under `/var/log/`, `~/Library/Logs` or `/Library/Logs`. Do you know where they are?

(Maybe there are no physical files, just the stdout of the python development environment and so the log is only available in the launcher application.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you surmise, and can confirm by studying the source file `/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py`, the logs are not being written to disk (a `cStringIO.StringIO` instance is used to keep them in memory, as the rest of the code *is* oriented to writing them "to a file-like object").

What I would recommend is writing your own app server script, which imports `dev_appserver`, subclasses `dev_appserver.ApplicationLoggingHandler`, and overrides just *one* method:

```
from google.appengine.tools import dev_appserver

class MyHandler(dev_appserver.ApplicationLoggingHandler):

    def __init__(self, *a, **k):
        dev_appserver.ApplicationLoggingHandler.__init__(self, *a, **k)
        self.thefile = open('/tmp/mylog.txt', 'w')

    def emit(self, record):
        dev_appserver.ApplicationLoggingHandler(self, record)
        self.thefile.write(str(record) + '\n')
        self.thefile.flush()
```

You also need to ensure this class is used instead of the standard one, e.g. by subclassing the dispatcher or ensuring you use its dependency-injection capability.  (`dev_appserver_main.py` lets you control this better, I think).

I think this customization approach is far more cumbersome than it should be (it's perfectly normal to want the logs written to file, after all -- either to display them differently, as you desire, or to process them later with some auxiliary script), and so I'd also recommend putting a feature request on app engine's tracker: `dev_appserver.py` should accept one more flag, which, if specified, gives the path on which to write logs to disk.

And, to be honest, if I needed this feature right now, myself, I'd do it the dirty way: editing that `.py` file (and its related `_main.py`) to add said flag and its use.  That should be a dozen lines in all, much easier than the "canonical" way I just outlined. Of course, it *is* dirty because every time there's a new SDK you'll have to apply the patch again, and again, and again... which is why one should *also* propose the patch on GAE's tracker, as part of the feature request I suggested, hoping it gets accepted soon!-)

Comment: Since doing this requires you to run the script yourself anyway (rather than via the launcher), you could just run "dev_appserver.py <...> | tee logfile"

Answer (score 5):

Many of these answers are now outdated. :)

In today's `devappserver`, use `--logs_path=LOGS_FILE` if you want to log to a file (in its native sqlite database format). Or as suggested in a comment, simply pipe the output if that's too complicated.

Since there's a log API, it actually now stores log entries in a file in `--storage_path` if not set. <s>I have noticed a few bugs myself, though.</s> (I'll assume they don't exist now, it's been a while since I used this.)

Comment: When I do this, SQLLite3 stuff gets stored in the file specified in --logs_path (I don't want SQLLite3 stuff, I don't know what it is), but the logs I want are written to the bash stdout (therefore piping as Nick Johnson suggests works for me).  Also what is --storage_path? Also what bugs did you notice? Thank you.

Comment: Piping works fine too. The sqlite3 stuff *is* the log data, though I think it might have been text earlier. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226078/how-to-decode-the-persisted-log-files-from-app-engines-python-dev-server or use an app such as those at https://www.google.ca/search?q=sqlite%20osx -- I edited my answer to reflect your comment. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thoughtful reply, thanks. Last comment, even piping didn't work, log stuff was just printed directly to shell (console?). Any idea about this? Is it a "TTY" issue? I am using Git Bash on Windows, same issue trying to pipe with normal Windows Cmd. Thanks +1.

Comment: And since at least the SQLLite3 stuff was written, (whereas piping didn't seem to write anything to disk; see previous comment.), I probably use your approach! Yay.

Answer (score 4):

A simple, and also dirty, fix is to add the following code into your dev_appserver.py file, towards the top:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig( filename='/tmp/gae.log', filemode='a' )
```

Obviously, change your logfile to what you want. This requires the least amount of change, and is the easiest to commit into your repo and diff when there's a new release.

**Update:**
Slightly better might be to make it into a command-line option:

```
def start_logging():
  import logging

  logfile=''
  for item in sys.argv[1:]:
    if re.match('--log_file=', item):
      logfile=item.split('=')[1]
      # Remove this item from sys.argv
      sys.argv.remove(item)
      break

  if logfile:
    print "Please monitor the log file (with tail -f %s)" % logfile
    logging.basicConfig( filename=logfile, filemode='a' )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the logs at runtime, they're printed on the command-line along with the HTTP calls.

`logging.debug()` and `logging.error()` are not printed, but calls `info` upwards are.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128409/973380) for a little more detail.