# Google App Engine Dev Server Logs Location

Tags: google-app-engine

Really simple question. I'm on Ubuntu 9.04 (I'm new to Ubuntu) and I can't find the dev server logs for GAE. Could somebody tell me where they are? Googling hasn't returned any result.

Comment: To whomever suggested that this should be moved to serverfault: this very definitely belongs on stackoverflow. This question is not really related to servers as such; it is about a component of the AppEngine SDK. Very related.

Comment: It would be great if there was a link to the logs in http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin like the local datastore viewer. Perhaps this would be a good feature request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does GoogleAppEngineLauncher keep the local log files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844635/where-does-googleappenginelauncher-keep-the-local-log-files)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I had the same question, and got an answer: [Where does GoogleAppEngineLauncher keep the local log files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844635/where-does-googleappenginelauncher-keep-the-local-log-files) (It's a Mac, not Ubuntu, but otherwise the question seems to be similar.)

In short: it turns out that these logs are not saved to a physical file but you can modify the  source code to get this result. Details are described at the above link.