# Google App Engine: Logging in dev console?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

Does logging work on the dev server? This code doesn't raise an exception, but I can't see where to view the logs in the devserver console. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place?

```
logging.error("error has occurred")
```

Comment: You can learn more about logging on GAE for [Python here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Logging), or [Java here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Logging).

Comment: A while ago, I submitted a feature request for a log viewer on the dev server. You can vote it up here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3289

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you create your logger.  This should work.

Code

```
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.error("uuu")
logging.info("ggg")
```

Launching from the CLI

```
$dev_appserver.py ~/workspace/helloworld/
```

The logs I got on the CLI...

```
ERROR    2012-11-26 03:02:25,467 helloworld.py:89] uuu
INFO     2012-11-26 03:02:25,467 helloworld.py:90] ggg
```

Note that this also works for me in Tornado.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, logging works on the dev server.  When dev_appserver.py is run from the command-line, you  should see output from logging calls such as the one you mentioned whenever they are called.

By default, only logging messages of INFO level and higher are printed.

Also, `logging.error()` does not raise an exception when called.  It simply logs the string you pass at the "error" level - on the development server, this basically just means it will print "ERROR" as part of the logging message on the development server.

Comment: Right, I meant that `logging.error()` wouldn't raise an exception as in a "this doesn't work on the devserver" exception.

I see the "logging" button in the devserver GUI window. Cool. How do I change which level of message is printed?

Comment: You can control what level of messages are printed using [`logging.setLevel()`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel).

Comment: Hmm.. Any hint about when the logging service starts?  In main.py, logging statements don't make it yet.

Comment: logging.setLevel doesn't exist: use logging.disable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the default logging level when starting the development server:

```
dev_appserver.py --log_level=debug ...
```

From [dev_appserver.py command-line arguments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=en#Python_Command-line_arguments):

> --log_level=...
>
> The lowest logging level at which logging messages will be written to the console; messages of the specified logging level or higher will
>   be output. Possible values are debug, info, warning, error, and
>   critical.