# Debugging task queues in development server?

Tags: google-app-engine

Simple question - I want to log activity that occurs in a task queue request. I want to print something to the console, such as `print('I made it this far')`, to know what exactly is happening in the function call. Is this possible?

Edit: For those who were not taught how to read "context clues" in elementary school, my question is: H-O-W?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What's your actual question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman great why don't you post that as an answer and I'll let you know if that's what I was looking for

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've edited my question with more details

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine: Logging in dev console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128393/google-app-engine-logging-in-dev-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable logging:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

```
logging.info('Signed by {0} user'.format(user_name))
```

And then check the log in the administration screen.

Comment: But what about in the development server..there is no logging section

Comment: See this answer, it seems to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128393/google-app-engine-logging-in-dev-console