# Alert message on Google App Engine for Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, alert

I want to pop an alert message for error handling on an app that runs via Google App Engine for Python.

I tried this already but non worked:

`from Tkinter import *
msg = Message(text="Please, make sure you fill out the boxes and agree with the terms")
msg.config(bg='green', font=('times', 16))
msg.pack()
mainloop()`

AND

```
import win32api
win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

I am guessing the Google App Engine has its own way of handling this task but I can't figure out how.

Thank you!

Comment: app engine cannot handle this sort of work. on what screen would you expect the GUI to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The GAE server suppose to run headless, so you can't display a popup in your host machine. If you use windows to launch de dev server, simply use the log buton from the GUI or launch your dev server from the command line.

To generate a debug log from your application you can simply see this post. [Google app engine logging in dev consol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128393/google-app-engine-logging-in-dev-console)

In production your application have a full admin panel with a lot of possibilities and a logging pannelto see all messages from your app.